# Lazy loading modules/files for multipage angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, browserify, webpack

I am tasked with a multi-page website that uses angularjs as a front-end framework. Currently, I used browserify with npm to manage the module dependencies, which generate a bundled file for the whole app. However, each page only use part of that bundled file (1 controller file and a few directive/service files). Is it possible to lazy load the files instead of one large bundled files?

I have read about webpack lazy-load, but I don't know if it does what I want (i.e. auto detect and load files, enable the use of npm package, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use require.ensure inside a function instead of simple require. In this case the module will be exported in other file and loaded only when needed. Here is an example:

```
function (callback) {
    require.ensure(['module'], function (require) {
        callback(require('module'));
    });
}
```

So 'module' loaded only when you call this function first time.